# Turkish Word Encryption in Python

Tags: python

I have an idea in python - how can I do this?

It should work like that

> Text Input

*`Rüzgar`*

> Process

- > ```
  >    R --> consonant
  >    ü --> vowel
  >    z --> consonant
  >    g --> consonant
  >    a --> vowel
  >    r --> consonant
  > ```

  - List the word
    [r,ü,z,g,a,r]

-If the first letter is consonant do nothing and go to second letter if second letter is vowel add "g" and add the same vowel again

> Rü**gü**zga**ga**r

and print it

First steps

```
text = "abcd"

word_list = []

for i in range(0, len(text)):
    word_list.append(text[i])
    i+=1

for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
 if(word_list[i]=='A' or word_list[i]=='a' or word_list[i]=='E' or word_list[i] =='e' or word_list[i]=='I'
 or word_list[i]=='i' or word_list[i]=='O' or word_list[i]=='o' or word_list[i]=='U' or word_list[i]=='u'):
    print(word_list[i], "is a Vowel")
    i+=1

else:
    print(word_list[i], "is a Consonant")
    i+=1
```

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4N1H.png)

I don't have any ideas to keep up the code and solve the first problems

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a "kuş dili" encoder? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, it is a "kuş dili" encoder. I updated my post with new details

Comment: There are multiple errors in the existing code. You shouldn't increment the loop variable (`i`) manually. The `for` statement does it for you. Also you don't have to convert a string into a list as strings are already iterables in Python. You should basically initialise another string to be used as the result, and keep appending the letters you find to this one. If the current letter is a wovel, you should also add "g" and the wovel one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one liner for you to study:

```
vowels = "aeiou"  # You may add vowels specific to Turkish alphabet here 
text = "hello world"

print("".join([letter + ("g" + letter if letter in vowels else "") for letter in text]))
```

will print

```
hegellogo wogorld
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your text. To make it easier, make text lower-cased.

```py
text = "rüzgar"
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'ı', 'i', 'u', 'ü', 'o', 'ö']

index = 0
for each_character in text.lower():
    if each_character in vowels:
        text = text[:index+1] + 'g' + each_character + text[index+1:]
    index = index + 1

print(text)
```

Output will be: `rügüzgagar`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(word):
    vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    word_list = list(word)
    for index, char in enumerate(word_list):
        if char in vowel:
            word_list[index] = '{}g{}'.format(char,char)
    return ''.join(word_list)


print(func('hello world!'))
```

ouput

```
hegellogo wogorld!
```